# Update con Panel

Tags: asp.net

Estoy tratando de realizer un `Update` a los registros que tengo en mi base de datos en `Access` al principio funcionaba y cambiaba todos los registros por que no tenia un `id = id`, despues lo coloque en el `Query` pero ya no funciona nada, no hace ningun `Update`

este es mi codigo:

```
string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

             using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
             {
                 using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
                 {
                     connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                     command.Connection = connection;
                     connection.Open();

                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(Txt_id.Text));
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", Dpo_status.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AREA", Dpo_buckets.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOOL", Txt_tool.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RESPONSABLE", Txt_resp.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTA", Txt_notas.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REPAIR", Txt_dates.Text.Trim());

                     command.CommandText = "UPDATE status_change SET status = @STATUS, area = @AREA, tool = @TOOL, responsable = @RESPONSABLE, nota = @NOTA, repair = @REPAIR, repare = 1 WHERE id = @ID";

                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
                     connection.Close();
                 }
             }
```

y este es el codigo del `Panel`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelEdit" runat="server" CssClass="panel panel-primary" Width="750px" Style="display: none">
        <asp:Panel ID="panelEditTitle" runat="server" CssClass="panel-heading">
            <h3 align="center"><span><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp Re-Assign Tool</i></span></h3>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div align="center">
                <div class="input-group col-xs-9" style="display: none">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">id</span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_id" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoComplete="off" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                &nbsp
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Responsable</span>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="Txt_resp" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_resp" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss a responsable" ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Area</span>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Dpo_buckets" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="False">
                                            <asp:ListItem>MCH</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_tool" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss the tool" ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Tool</span>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="Txt_tool" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true" />
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_tool" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss the tool" ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Status</span>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Dpo_status" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="False">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Dpo_status" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select a status" ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Nota</span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notas" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_notas" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You need to assign a note" ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Date</span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_dates" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true"/>
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_dates" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select the current date" ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitBT" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="edit" OnClick="SubmitBT_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="DismissBT" runat="server" Text="Dismiss" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Y hay algun Id como el que estas mandando?

Comment: claro, todo lo traigo de la base de datos, hago un BrackPoint y si tiene el valor del id correspondiente del registro que quiero editar

Comment: y ese update directamente en la bd si funciona???

Comment: Efectivamente pero ya lo solucione, ponder mi respuesta, Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo!!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void SubmitBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

             using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
             {
                 using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
                 {
                     connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                     command.Connection = connection;
                     connection.Open();

                     int id = Convert.ToInt32((Txt_id.Text));
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", Dpo_status.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AREA", Dpo_buckets.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOOL", Txt_tool.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RESPONSABLE", Txt_resp.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTA", Txt_notas.Text.Trim());
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REPAIR", Txt_dates.Text.Trim());

                     command.CommandText = "UPDATE status_change SET status = @STATUS, area = @AREA, tool = @TOOL, responsable = @RESPONSABLE, nota = @NOTA, repair = @REPAIR, repare = 1 WHERE id = @ID";

                     command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id;

                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
                     connection.Close();
                 }
             }
        }
```